# Spark Job fails due to java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage

Tags: scala, apache-spark, playframework, sbt, netty

I want to run a spark job but this is the error I am getting:

```
[warn] o.a.s.d.c.AppClient$ClientEndpoint - Failed to connect to master 127.0.0.1:7077
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5447855329526097695, local class serialVersionUID = -2221986757032131007
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:258)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:570)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:149)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:104)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:186)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
```

It all boils down to this

```
[warn] o.a.s.d.c.AppClient$ClientEndpoint - Failed to connect to master 127.0.0.1:7077
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5447855329526097695, local class serialVersionUID = -2221986757032131007
```

My project is a Play Scala. I'm using Java 8, Scala 2.11.8, Spark 1.6.1 and Cassandra 1.6.0-M2.

I have checked several other similar reported problems but in most cases there was an incompatibility between the spark version running on the machine (I am running a local standalone) and the library dependencies. In both cases I have made sure I'm running 'spark 1.6.1' and all my external dependencies reflect this version only.

The stranger things is that a similar project (they have the same sbt, same structure and functions, just different classes) runs smoothly with these settings but this particular project simply does not.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the version of Spark that you're using compiled for Scala 2.11?  By default, Spark 1.6.1 is compiled for Scala 2.10.

Comment: I'm using 2.11 but ironically up until 2 days ago I was running spark 1.6.1 with 2.11, flawlessly. And even now the error only happens for a particular project. Another one, very similar, same sbt files and runs on spark 1.6.1 and scala 2.11 works fine.

Comment: I would definitely try to get the 1.6.1 version of spark compiled in Scala 2.11 for runtime. Do you get this inside your IDE (e.g., while unit testing) or when you run on an actual cluster?

Comment: That's exactly what I had running (Spark 1.6.1 and scala 2.11). The error I got when I ran on the cluster through the IDE.